# 'socket.timeout: timed out' error using python requests library

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib

I am trying to connect to site with proxy:

```
import requests
import socket

# ...

def getLink(proxy, userAgent, link):
    try:
        # ...

        proxies = {'http': proxy}
        headers = {'User-Agent': userAgent}
        r = requests.get(link, headers=headers, proxies=proxies, timeout=10)

        # ...

    except (socket.timeout, requests.exceptions.TimeoutException, RequestException, socket.error):
        print('Timeout error! Retrying...')
        return 0
```

Running this code with bad proxy, in 10 seconds I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 80, in create_connection
raise err
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 70, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
 socket.timeout: timed out

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 ...
```

On the github, I read that this is a urllib library bug, and that there are problems with its handling. How can I handle it in the *try except* construction?

Comment: Things to check 1.) Is your proxy on a block list 2.) Is your proxy still active 3.) Does the server only accept http and https connections or just https?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I only need to handle this error, and the construction of try except does not help in this.